# Filter Spark dataframe by checking if value is in the list of particular column or not in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have spark df as follows:

```
Name country
A     ["GB","USA","IN"]
B     ["GB","RU"]
C     ["IN","BN"]
D     ["GB"]
```

I am trying to filter this spark df with `"GB"`. Output should be like that:

```
Name country
A     ["GB","USA","IN"]
B     ["GB","RU"]
D     ["GB"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `array_contains` function.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.where(F.array_contains(F.col('country'), 'GB'))
```